# Vb.net Exporting Richtextbox formated content to Excel Cell

Tags: vb.net, excel, richtextbox

Further to my first question regarding that issue, here are my progress:

First : using the function: `sheet.Cells(X, X).Value = RichTextBox1.Rtf`, I find this kind of cell content:

```
"rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1036\deflangfe1036{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\f2\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue139;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs22 XXXXXXXXXXX\par
\cf1\strike\f1 XXXXXXXXXXX\par"
```

I can however manually use the excel function "keep the original formatting" to paste some rtf doc content into a cell.

Could you help me find a way to use this function in the VB.net code if possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of yourself: [Exporting Richtextbox content to Excel Cell with formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486193/exporting-richtextbox-content-to-excel-cell-with-formatting)

Comment: Please don't post questions again. You can edit to improve your older question or, when you have 75 reputation, offer a bounty in it.

Comment: Ok sorry, I wont do it again.